# How can I do something like this with ruby arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an user array like this:

```
users_array = [[1,text for 1],[2,text for 2],[3,text for 3],[4,text for 4],[5,text for 5]]
```

here first element is user_id and second element is text which is specific to user_id in the same array.

Now I am trying to have user object from instead of ids in array like these.

```
users_array = [[#<User id: 1, encrypted_email: "">,text for 1],[#<User id: 2, encrypted_email: "">,text for 2],[#<User id: 3, encrypted_email: "">,text for 3],[#<User id: 4, encrypted_email: "">,text for 4],[#<User id: 5, encrypted_email: "">,text for 5]]
```

I am trying not to loop the array and hit the db thousand times for thousands user.

Comment: How will you get the user object for a given id without querying the database ?

Comment: Use `includes` if the **text** is associated with `User`

Comment: Try to use valid Ruby code in your examples, e.g. use `"text for 1"` instead of `text for 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = users_array.to_h
# find all users with single query and build your map
User.where(id: data.keys).map { |user| [user, data[user.id]] }
```

Comment: `users_array = Hash[users_array]`

Comment: `users_array.to_h` would work as well, but assigning a hash to a variable called `users_array` looks a bit dirty.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) to extract ids and values, and [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) to combine users and values:

```
ids, values = users_array.transpose
users_array = User.find(ids).zip(values)
```